# Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am getting this error while accessing the Postgres database through pgAdmin.

I already set the method as "trust"

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the port(8888) it looks like you are trying to connect to a Web server. Postgres by default runs on port 5432 and if not there generally in the 54** range. Verify what port your port Postgres is running on. I would start with what port is set to in postgresql.conf. You don't say what OS you are using, so I can't offer a command to check listening ports.